# IE11: open jquery dialog to load external url in standards mode when the root html page is in quirks mode

Tags: dialog, jquery-ui-dialog, sapui5, quirks-mode

This requirement is on SAP Portal. The current version of Portal doesn't allow me to integrate SAP UI5 application on IE, primarily due to SAP Portal runs on Quirks mode, and UI5 runs on standards mode. We are on IE11, so no issues in Chrome/FF. So, the solution SAP proposes is to open the UI5 application in a new window, and the customer is not happy with this solution. So I was looking for ways to handle this using JQuery. As the Portal runs on Quirks mode (root) when I open the UI5 application (iframe/div) on a jquery dialog its resulting in opening in Quirks mode only.

I've read few posts in SO in similar context, so checking with the experts here to see if there is a way or solution to open/load ui5 application in standards mode using JQuery or JS, as it can't run in quirks mode in IE while on Portal.

Let me know if i need to provide any more details, as my earlier post was put on hold.

Comment: Hi, Anyone can comment if this is possible in IE11 environment and not worth of trying this approach? Please share your experiences!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the solution that SAP proposes is the only one available to you.

IE **absolutely cannot** render standards mode and quirks mode in the same page, not even if they are in different frames or iframes.

The only way you can mix between the two is by having them in separate windows.

It's worth adding here that anything still running in quirks mode is living on borrowed time. Quirks mode is not supported in Microsoft's new Edge browser. For now, you can still run IE11, but there will come a time when support for IE11 is dropped and Edge will become the only MS browser. At that point, you will not be able to use anything that requires quirks mode. I would urge you to plan to make the upgrade now while the transition will be easy, rather than waiting till it is forced on you.